# How to work with Pycharm + Jupyter in local which access data from cluster?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to work in Pycharm in local system (mac) which connect and execute the code via jupyter installed on Hadoop edge nodes ?

We have a requirement from data scientist who would like to read data from HDFS using spark and plot some graphs or run some models in pycharm (mac) snippet by snippet.

Really interested to know if this model is possible or how generally data scientist work in big data eco system from local machine to read data from HDFS to run some models ?

Comment: Why not write python script in Pycharm and run it on remote server? Or load that jupyter notebook in Pycharm and run. I don't think that you invoke jupyter on remote server. You either run jupyter on local and run commands on remote via ssh tunnel, or load jupyter in Pycharm and run on remote server or just write python script in Pycharm and run on remote server.

Comment: Could you help to understand more ? If i would like to have code in GIT which could be cloned in pycharm where i want to run the code in pycharm which should get data from HDFS and plot some graphs (not a as a project , interactive mode snippet by snippet ) ? Somewhere if jupyterlab could be used its fine. ultimately trying to achieve this working model. Some advice would be great to hear. @Vishal

Comment: If you want to run everything on you local computer and your local computer can fetch data from HDFS, then you don't need jupyter at all. You have to write a python script to connect, this is pain but it is only one time, to HDFS and fetch data. But if you want to run everything on some remote node which is connected to HDFS, then you have two options.

Comment: 1. Either run your pycharm code on remote node and fetch data from HDFS (here also you need to write one time connection script). 2. you run jupyter on remote node and through SSH tunneling, you open that jupyter notebook on your local computer and run code (here also you need to write one time connection to HDFS script). In 2nd case pycharm does not comes into picture. If on your GIT, you only have jupyter notebooks, then 2nd options is good for you.

Comment: I managed to install jupyterlab in remote machine and accessed jupyter in local machine browser by tunneling. Instead of browser is it possible to run through pycharm ? I see some integration exist with pycharm and jupyter.

Comment: It is possible to run from pycharm, but it is not recommended option. You may face some more challenges when compared to running in browser.

Comment: If you could tell me how to configure in pycharm that’s great. Thanks for helping till the conclusion

Comment: You need to configure your interpreter settings to run on remote sever. Check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-remote-python-sdks.html#SSH). Once it is setup, everything will run on the remote server.

Comment: @vbrises Thanks I followed your suggestion and completed. One more question.If datascientist use Jupyter from remote machine using ssh and access HDFS data from cluster in mac, How could they install required lib like panda and so on specific to their project ? or the lib has to be always installed on the remote machine by admin who installed jupyter ?

Comment: It would be specific to python you are using, not project. Other project can use same library. You can create a .txt file and on every line have the libraries that you want for this project, and do pip install <name>.txt and it will install all packages listed in the .txt file. I am not sure whether I had answer your question correctly or not.

Comment: I understand you point. @vbrises if we have virtual env and point to the specific python version what jupyter using and install lib using pip in virtual env, do you think we can import the installed lib in jupyter ?